# Input redirect me on the wrong view

Tags: django

Hello i'm a beginner at django and i got this problem. (i don't know if the code i put is enough)

When i decide to create a new comment, if i click on "create" instead of redirect me to "usercomments" and send the data to the database, it log me out and send me where log out is supposed to send me. i can't find a similar problem, i don't even know what kind of error it is, help

Thanks :)

Templates of "create comment" :

```
<div class="create-comment">
        <h2>Write a comment</h2>
        <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'usercomments:create' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'usercomments'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.comments_list, name="list"),
    url(r'^create/$', views.comments_create, name="create"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',views.comments_detail, name="detail"),
    ]
```

Views of create comment :

```
@login_required(login_url="/userprofile/login/")
def comments_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateComment(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # save article to db
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('usercomments:list')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateComment()
    return render(request, 'usercomments/comments_create.html', { 'form': form })
```

Views of log out :

```
def logout_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        return redirect('/')    <--- Where i get redirected when i press "create"
    else:
        pass
```

Urls of logout :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name = 'userprofile'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_view, name="signup"),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.logout_view, name="logout"),
]
```

Comment: add your views.comments_list

Comment: This is because your @login_required decorator. It seems like you’re not signed in before the comments create request